# Can we reuse a Gson object?

Tags: java, json, gson

Can we reuse a `Gson` object, or one `Gson` object should be used for one conversion (to or from `JSON`)? I met here on SO a few not quite clear and kind of contradictory explanations so I wanted to ask this again.

Comment: @RC. Come on, try what exactly... ?! :) Under some conditions it may work, under others - not. It depends on the contract, I mean on the specification/design itself.

Comment: You can easily use a single instance any times. `Gson` is thread-safe. The only difference I'm thinking of is that your `Gson` instances can be configured using different type adapters that might use different serialization/deserialization strategies + configuration options built with `GsonBuilder`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the [user guide](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Gson-Performance-and-Scalability):

> The Gson instance does not maintain any state while invoking Json operations. So, you are free to reuse the same object for multiple Json serialization and deserialization operations.

Comment: OK, well... thanks. I was not even sure where the official documentation is. Previously it was in some other format and under a different URL, I think.

Comment: What about thread-safety? Some people here on SO were claiming it's not really thread-safe.

Comment: yep google-code has moved to github (I don't know exactly when). About thread safety, I trust google, when they say no state.